# Pandas .loc multiple assignment versus a single one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with timestamp index (tens of thousands of items) and a list of timestamps which correspond to some events. I need to mark all items from the dataframe which happen n minutes before any of the events, so I wrote the following code:

```
for timestamp in events:
    df.loc[timestamp - timespan : timestamp, 'is_before_event'] = True
```

It turned out to be very slow, so I tried to first build up an index of all the elements that have to be changed and then do a single assignment on all of them:

```
for timestamp in events:
    temp_index = temp_index.append(df.loc[timestamp - timespan : timestamp].index)
df.loc[df.index.isin(temp_index), 'is_before_event'] = True
```

This code runs at least 100 times faster than my first attempt.

Why is it so and what is the proper way of doing assignment in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can assign boolean mask to column without `loc` if need `True` and `False` values.

Also is necessary use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for join all indexes together with [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) for remove duplicates.

```
temp_index = []
for timestamp in events:
     temp_index.append(df.loc[timestamp - timespan : timestamp].index)
df['is_before_event'] = df.index.isin(np.concatenate(temp_index))
```

Sample (with list comprehension what is same as solution above):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=20, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(20)}, index=rng)  
#print (df)

events = pd.to_datetime(['2017-04-03 00:03:00', '2017-04-03 00:09:45'])
t = pd.Timedelta('00:03:00')

temp_index = [df.loc[timestamp - t : timestamp].index for timestamp in events]
idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(temp_index))
df['is_before_event'] = df.index.isin(idx)
print (df)
                      a  is_before_event
2017-04-03 00:00:00   0             True
2017-04-03 00:01:00   1             True
2017-04-03 00:02:00   2             True
2017-04-03 00:03:00   3             True
2017-04-03 00:04:00   4            False
2017-04-03 00:05:00   5            False
2017-04-03 00:06:00   6            False
2017-04-03 00:07:00   7             True
2017-04-03 00:08:00   8             True
2017-04-03 00:09:00   9             True
2017-04-03 00:10:00  10            False
2017-04-03 00:11:00  11            False
2017-04-03 00:12:00  12            False
2017-04-03 00:13:00  13            False
2017-04-03 00:14:00  14            False
2017-04-03 00:15:00  15            False
2017-04-03 00:16:00  16            False
2017-04-03 00:17:00  17            False
2017-04-03 00:18:00  18            False
2017-04-03 00:19:00  19            False
```

Similar solution:

```
temp_index = [df.loc[timestamp - t : timestamp].index for timestamp in events]
idx = np.unique(np.concatenate(temp_index))
df['is_before_event'] = False
df.loc[idx, 'is_before_event'] = True
print (df)
                      a  is_before_event
2017-04-03 00:00:00   0             True
2017-04-03 00:01:00   1             True
2017-04-03 00:02:00   2             True
2017-04-03 00:03:00   3             True
2017-04-03 00:04:00   4            False
2017-04-03 00:05:00   5            False
2017-04-03 00:06:00   6            False
2017-04-03 00:07:00   7             True
2017-04-03 00:08:00   8             True
2017-04-03 00:09:00   9             True
2017-04-03 00:10:00  10            False
2017-04-03 00:11:00  11            False
2017-04-03 00:12:00  12            False
2017-04-03 00:13:00  13            False
2017-04-03 00:14:00  14            False
2017-04-03 00:15:00  15            False
2017-04-03 00:16:00  16            False
2017-04-03 00:17:00  17            False
2017-04-03 00:18:00  18            False
2017-04-03 00:19:00  19            False
```